# How to fill entire window with image and allow resizing of window?

Tags: c++, gtk2

I need an image to be resized to entire window and maintain the option to shrink/resize window.
As a separate task it is easily accomplished but not together.
Example code that I use is:

```
    myWindow = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(myWindow), "name");
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(myWindow), myWidth, myHeight);
    gtk_window_set_resizable(GTK_WINDOW(myWindow), TRUE);
    g_signal_connect(myWindow, "delete-event", G_CALLBACK(PrivDeleteEvent), this);
    g_signal_connect(myWindow, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(PrivOnDestroy), this);

    myImage = gtk_image_new();

    GtkWidget* container = gtk_alignment_new(0, 0, 1, 1);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(myWindow), container);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(container), myImage);

    g_signal_connect(myImage, "expose-event", G_CALLBACK(PrivOnImageExposeEvent), this);

    gtk_widget_show_all(myWindow);

    gtk_main();

void 
PrivSetImage()
{
    GdkPixbuf* pixbuf = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_data(...);
    gtk_image_set_from_pixbuf(GTK_IMAGE(myImage), pixbuf);
}
```

After image widget resized I call some rendering stuff and then show it in the GtkImage itself. This works good, i see image and I am able to resize window. But after gtk_image_set_from_pixbuf called I no longer able to shrink window smaller than size used to create Pixbuf. As if somewhere inside there is a call to gtk_widget_set_size_request with Pixbuf dimensions which blocks window to shrink past pixbuf size.
Any suggestion ?